# Seleium/Ruby - NoSuchElement when trying to access an item in a modal popup

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

What I'm attempting:

1. Click on a the profile picture of a user that I previously created:  http://screencast.com/t/AJCFI3XA
2. Click on and make a selection from a drop down in the pop up modal: 
   http://screencast.com/t/AHGOHlG05

The `selenium IDE` picks up the steps as:

1. click > `id=patientPhoto`
2. selectWindow >  `name=modal3` (**NOTE** that the modal number changes and increases exponentially, if i run these steps again the next time around it's modal4)
3. click > `id=ext-gen115` click > `//div[@id='ext-gen179']/div[2]`

This playback in the ide works without issue.

My code:

```
@driver.find_element(:id, "patientPhoto").click
wait_for { displayed?(:id, "ext-gen31") }
@driver.find_element(:id, "ext-gen31").click
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@id='ext-gen179']/div[2]").click
```

In other places/workflows I have to do the switch to default content then switch to frame trick:

```
@driver.switch_to.default_content
@driver.switch_to.frame('chartFrame')
```

but no combination of that is working here.

Other things I've tried:

```
1.  Switch to the last window like this:  @driver.switch_to.window(@driver.window_handles.last) # this doesn't fail but the step after this (finding the drop down) fails
2.  @driver.switch_to.frame('modal4') then attempt to access the items in the modal  # this fails i think because the modal number keeps changing
```

Here's the page coding - http://screencast.com/t/OSIIgjxDbLk

The `selenium` errors I get vary based on what I'm attempting but it's either timeout or cannot find element.

Comment: Do not provide `HTML` code as a picture! You should add `HTML` code for target elements as text directly to your question! To switch to correct `iframe` you should use  `@driver.switch_to.frame('modal1')`. After that you can handle required element. `@driver.switch_to.default_content` used to **switch back from** `iframe`

Comment: I'm totally calm :) Try `@driver.switch_to.frame(@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//iframe[contains(@id, 'modal')]"))`

Comment: YES!!!!!!!! SO Simple yet so perfect! Amazing, thank you! Do you want to submit this as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an `iframe` with dynamic `id`, try to use following line of code to switch to it:

```
@driver.switch_to.frame(@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//iframe[contains(@id, 'modal')]"))
```